# How to return static value from static query

Tags: mysql, sql

In sql i need to get my own values.
For example :

Select House from dual ( here i need to return H ) from dual union all
select Build from dual ( here i need to return B) ...

I tired with this but i dont get it as  I want

select '18776' as instanceid from dual union all
select '18775' as instanceid from dual

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode it like

```
Select 'H' from dual
union all
select 'B' from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

@mikrimouse simply just write hard code in a query like:

```
select 'H' from dual
union all
select 'B' from dual
```

Comment: two minutes too late :-(

Comment: I think Tim's referring to Rahul's answer, @BunkerBoy (which was posted two minutes before yours and includes identical information)

Comment: @BunkerBoy You don't have to delete, but realize that SO is a bit of a Mexican standoff.  With a question like this, the first to post is often the one who wins.

Comment: 2 minutes is an eternity on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i don't want to win, let the asker win

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're coming from an Oracle background. Oracle is unique in requiring a FROM clause among the DBMSes I've used (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL).

You should be good just having:

```
select 'H'
union all
select 'B'
```